# highest row count

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have `TableA` which contains:

```
ID   |  CATEGORY   |    NAME
-------------------------
1    |   A         |   NAME01
2    |   B         |   NAME02
3    |   C         |   NAME03
4    |   D         |   NAME04
5    |   B         |   NAME05
```

So how can I count which of the Categorys in my table I have the most?
We can see it is the Category B, but in my real table I have more than 200 records added.
In the table I have 5 different Categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can just use an aggregate function (`count()`) and a `group by`:

```
select category, count(category) Total
from TableA
group by category
order by Total desc
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79627/2)

If you then want to return only the record with the most, you can add a `LIMIT` to it:

```
select category, count(category) Total
from TableA
group by category
order by Total Desc
limit 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79627/3)

Comment: Okay this is perfect, but how do I output not the number of count but the name of category? For me it returns only the count.

Comment: @user1959221 the `category` name is in the select list, so for your sample data the query is showing the category B and a count of 2. Are you not seeing that in the demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79627/2?